# Dismiss modal and change tab with Wix React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Is it possible to dismiss a modal and automatically change tab with Wix react-native-navigation `4.2.0`.

This is what I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
  Navigation.dismissModal(componentId, {
      options: {
        bottomTabs: {
          currentTabIndex: 1,
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve this is by using `events` and `eventEmitter3` library

in events.js

```
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3';

export const events = new EventEmitter();
```

in Modal.js

```
  redirectToMyTab = () => {
    const { componentId } = this.props;
    events.emit('RedirectToMyTab');
    Navigation.dismissModal(componentId);
  };
```

And inside of one of tabs (as they are all mounted)

Tab0.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    events.on('RedirectToMyTab', this.redirectToMyTab);
  }

  redirectToMyTab = () => {
    const { componentId } = this.props;
    Navigation.mergeOptions(componentId, {
      bottomTabs: {
        currentTabIndex: 1,
      },
    });
  };
```